# error when i performSegueWithIdentifier

Tags: objective-c, xcode, storyboard

```
@implementation loadingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // send request
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

//inserting the response Data in database

[self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadingMenuSegue" sender:self];

}

@end
```

i have this error

*** Assertion failure in -[UIWindowController transition:fromViewController:toViewController:target:didEndSelector:], /SourceCache/UIKit_Sim/UIKit-1914.84/UIWindowController.m:188

*** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInternalInconsistencyException', reason: 'Attempting to begin a modal transition from  to  while a transition is already in progress. Wait for viewDidAppear/viewDidDisappear to know the current transition has completed'

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
@implementation loadingViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // send request
}

-(void)connectionDidFinishLoading:(NSURLConnection *)connection{

//inserting the response Data in database

//remove perform Segue from her, because the process is not finish yet
// [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadingMenuSegue" sender:self];

}

-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadingMenuSegue" sender:self];
}

@end
```

Answer (score 1):

That error likely indicates that your `connectionDidFinishLoading:` method is being called before `viewDidAppear:`. Since you can't perform a segue at that point, you might want to hold onto some state (so that you know the connection is finished) in an ivar or property, then in your `viewDidAppear:` implementation you can test that state and perform the segue if needed.

Comment: thank you 
-(void)viewDidAppear:(BOOL)animated{
    [super viewDidAppear:animated];
    [self performSegueWithIdentifier:@"loadingMenuSegue" sender:self];
}

Comment: Be careful; if you don't test to make sure that `performSegue...` only happens when the view appears right after loading your URL, it'll also happen when your view appears for other reasons (such as after coming back from a segue).